# Unable to delete WF 2013: "Workflow revision number mismatch"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-server

I can't delete my 2013 workflow.

When I try to delete it with SPD, nothing happens. SPD does a refresh but the workflow is not deleted.

When I try it directly in SharePoint, I get an error:

> "HTTP request failed after 20000 millisecondes"

ULS LOG told me :

> Workflow revision number mismatch! Current workflow store revision is
>   160 and workflow host scope has revision 0.

How can I definitly remove this WF ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with one of my client. Try to change the machine and SP Designer.

This normally happens when the workflow store revision number and the host which actually respond to the workflow has a mismatch of the revision number.

Make sure your Workflow farm architecture exists on ODD number of servers i.e 1 or 3. This is officially from Microsoft to install workflow manager on 1 or 3 servers.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193434(v=azure.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I did a complete reinstallation of workflow manager and now it"s working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For people where the solution doesn't work. 
The error: Workflow revision number mismatch! is not the problem.

I was digging around the mismatch, its just that workflow manager doesn't give the scope-revision number back through a header "Scope-Revision" SharePoint expects.

I had another issue, which is solved now, but the error still shows up. Though everything about my workflows works (deleting, adding, updating, associating and the workflows itself).

For me it was that the web-url changed from http://sharepoint/ (November 2015 CU) to http://sharepoint (July 2016 CU). So http://sharepoint_api was called instead of http://sharepoint/_api.

Someone else could have a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error message appeared also in my ULS, when I was trying to activate a sandboxed web feature containing a workflow.

For me, this was the solution:
http://sharepoint1083.rssing.com/browser.php?indx=4132529&item=63:

1. create a separate feature for workflows only
2. move all workflows in this separate feature and add no other modules or sharepoint artefacts like lists or site definitions in there.

Comment: Please add the solution steps in the answer to avoid the broken links in the future!!