# Unable to delete 2013 Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer-workflow, workflow2013

I am trying to delete a test workflow on SharePoint Designer but unable to. The cursor will spin for a minute or two, then the screen will refresh, but the workflow is still there. I was able to remove 2010 workflows, but 2013 will not delete. Also, when I go to the associated library in SharePoint, the workflow isn't listed there anymore, but still listed in SharePoint Designer. Incase it helps, I do not have access to PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

Try couple of things:

- close the SPD, complete logout and re-login
- clear the [SharePoint designer cache](http://www.letsharepoint.com/how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-cache-2010-2013/).

Comment: Unfortunately I've already tried that and neither worked.

Comment: can you republish the same workflow? and can you create a new workflow for same list then publish it?

Comment: Yes I can do both.

Comment: thats works? if it published successfully, then try to delete it again.

Comment: check this : https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/177478/unable-to-delete-wf-2013-workflow-revision-number-mismatch